# Bad results when using TimeSpan in Where with MySQL and Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

### We have table "Tasks":

```
Id | ToTime
1  | 23:59:59
```

### And code:

```
TimeSpan currentTime = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
var count = context.Tasks.Where(p => p.ToTime > currentTime).Count();
```

### The problem:

Theoretically, `count` should be always equals to 1 (in a daytime). But that not so cause sometimes (in random time) MySQL finds no rows (count = 0).

### Why?

Take a look at answer. It took 5 hours to find solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Milliseconds

Entity Framework generate SQL like this:

```
SELECT
`GroupBy1`.`A1` AS `C1`
FROM (SELECT
COUNT(1) AS `A1`
FROM `Tasks` AS `Extent1`
 WHERE `Extent1`.`ToTime` > '0 04:24:49.1438543') AS `GroupBy1`
```

But MySQL allowing only 6 digits for milliseconds. From [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-literals.html):

> A trailing fractional seconds part is recognized in the 'D
>   HH:MM:SS.fraction', 'HH:MM:SS.fraction', 'HHMMSS.fraction', and
>   HHMMSS.fraction time formats, where fraction is the fractional part in
>   up to microseconds (6 digits) precision. Although this fractional part
>   is recognized, it is discarded from values stored into TIME columns.

Extra digits appears because of redundancy TimeSpan and EntityFramework do not cuts that extra digits. Yep, looks like a bug. If someone know where to report it - please report or send link in comments.

### And what to do?

The solution is quite simple. MySQL does not use milliseconds in Time and just discart it. So we can discart it before request. Final code:

```
TimeSpan currentTime = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
// Re-creating TimeSpan to discart/cut milliseconds
currentTime = new TimeSpan(currentTime.Hours, currentTime.Minutes, currentTime.Seconds);
var count = context.Tasks.Where(p => p.ToTime > currentTime).Count();
```

And generated SQL would be always with 6 digits (000000). That resolves the problem.

### Bug?

As I said before that look like a bug. So if you know where to report it - please report or send link in comments.

Comment: One can use `TIME(6)` (fractional seconds [see MySQL doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fractional-seconds.html)) in MySQL. But remember, .NET `TimeSpan` has a fractional precision of 7 digits!